# NHibernate entity not updated after adding child element

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have an entry that contains a list of comments as seen in the mapping file bellow.

My scenario:

1. I add a new comment for a given entry (as seen in SaveComment method) and commit the changes
2. afterwards i query the comments on the entry domain object but my new comment is not yet added

Is NHibnerate using an out of date cache data here? How can I solve this?

```
using (ITransaction transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        Entry entry = Session.Load<Entry>(message.EntryId);

        Comment comment = SaveComment(entry, new BroadcastMetadata { some data });

        transaction.Commit();

        // I access the entry.LatestBroadcast info here 
        // but my entry doesnt have the new comment assigned yet !
        var latestData = entry.LatestBroadcast; // is null
    }
}

private Comment SaveComment(Entry entry, BroadcastMetadata broadcastMetadata)
{
    Session.Save(broadcastMetadata);

    var comment = new Comment
    {
        Entry = entry
        OldBroadcastData = entry.LatestBroadcast,
        NewBroadcastData = broadcastMetadata
    };
    Session.Save(comment);

    return comment;
}
```

My C# classes:

```
public class Entry
{
    public virtual BroadcastMetadata LatestBroadcast
    {
        get
        {
            BroadcastMetadata latestBroadcast = null;

            Comment broadcastComment = Comments.LastOrDefault();
            if (broadcastComment != null)
            {
                latestBroadcast = broadcastComment.NewBroadcastData;
            }
            else
            {
                latestBroadcast = BroadcastData;
            }

            return latestBroadcast;
        }
    }

    public virtual IList<Comment> Comments { get; protected set; }
}
```

My mappings:

```
<class name="Entry" table="`LogbookEntry`">

  <bag name="Comments" table="LogbookComment" lazy="false" inverse="true">
     <key column="EntryId" />
     <one-to-many 
       class="LogbookService.Core.Model.Comment, LogbookService.Core" />
  </bag>
```

```
<class name="Comment" table="LogbookComment">

  <many-to-one name="Entry" column="EntryId" fetch="join" lazy="false" cascade="none"
      class="LogbookService.Core.Model.Entry, LogbookService.Core" />

</class>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is, that the C# code inside `using {}` statement is not assigning the `Comment` to `Entry`. In this case NHibernate only serves to publish all the changes into DB.

Othe words:

- the `Comment` will be persisted
- it will contain the reference to `Entry` *(EntryId column will contain correct value)*
- once later `Entry` would be loaded, it will contain referencing `Comment`

So, NHibernate works properly.

But, in the code snippet, we are working with C# code, which is not effected by changes in persistence. So we have to explicitly also add the `Comment` into `Entry` collection. Just a pure C# entity handling:

```
var comment = new Comment
{
    Entry = entry
    ...
};
entry.Comments.Add(comment)
```

*NOTE: you are turning off the lazy `settings`, and I guess you have really good reason for that. But I would at least extend the bag mapping with batch: `<bag name="Comments" ... batch-size="25">`. Read more here [19.1.5. Using batch fetching](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch)*

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that you are requesting the last comment within the transaction scope, that means NHibernate hasn't disposed the transaction yet and potentially still fetching cache data, although it's committed already. Try this:

```
using (ITransaction transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
     {
        try
        {
           Entry entry = Session.Load<Entry>(message.EntryId);
           Comment comment = SaveComment(entry, new BroadcastMetadata { some data });
           transaction.Commit();
        }
     }

     // i access the entry.LatestBroadcast info here but my entry doesnt have the new comment assigned yet !
     var latestData = entry.LatestBroadcast; // is null
```

If that doesn't work. Try flushing the session after committing the transaction by doing **Session.Flush()**. Hope this helps!